# Accessing parts of match in Perl 6

Tags: raku

When I use a named regex, I can print its contents:

```perl6
my regex rgx { \w\w };
my $string = 'abcd';

$string ~~ / <rgx> /;
say $<rgx>; # ｢ab｣
```

But if I want to match with `:g` or `:ex` adverb, so there is more than one match, it doesn't work. The following

```perl6
my regex rgx { \w\w };
my $string = 'abcd';

$string ~~ m:g/ <rgx> /;
say $<rgx>; # incorrect
```

gives an error:

```perl6
Type List does not support associative indexing.
  in block <unit> at test1.p6 line 5
```

How should I modify my code?

**UPD:** Based on @piojo's [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033196/7730888), I modified the last line as follows and that solved my problem:

```perl6
say $/[$_]<rgx> for ^$/.elems;
```

The following would be easier, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```perl6
say $_<verb> for $/; # incorrect
```

Comment: the reason why `say $_<verb> for $/` doesn't do what you want it to is that using `$/` literally will be interpreted as "only loop over a single thing here". If you re-contextualize `$/` as a list by either `@$/` or `$/.list` you get the desired behavior. (In general, `for $blah` will give you a single iteration. Exceptions include if `$blah` has a `Slip` or if you have bound a value without its scalar container using the `:=` operator)

Comment: @timotimo Thank you very much!! `@$/` is exactly what I need, it's very useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `:g` and `:overlap` are special cases: if your match is repeated within the regex, like `/ <rgx>* /`, then you would access the matches as `$<rgx>[0]`, `$<rgx>[1]`, etc.. But in this case, the engine is doing the whole match more than once. So you can access those matches through the top-level match operator, `$/`. In fact, `$<foo>` is just a shortcut for `$/<foo>`.

So based on the error message, we know that in this case, `$/` is a list. So we can access your matches as `$/[0]<rgx>` and `$/[1]<rgx>`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So `$/` is split into two (matches) "before" the `<rgx>` branch, so my trying to access it via $/<rgs> was meaningless. @piojo Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I can't say with authority, but that's how it looks to me. You're welcome!

Comment: It seems that even if there is only one match, using `:ex` makes `$/` a list (with one element), so I can access `<rgx>` only via `$/[0]<rgx>`.

Comment: That's good. Consistency is very important. If you couldn't statically know whether to access the data as `$foo<x>` or `$foo[$n]<x>`, it would be hard to write correct programs.